# How encryption PDF password on firebase cloud function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, pdf, google-cloud-platform

I use node-qpdf npm on firebase cloud functions
but I don't understand about the path pdf file on firebase storage
how can I get a local path on firebase storage for node-qpd

example node-qpdf on firebase function

```
var qpdf = require('node-qpdf');
var options = {
keyLength: 128,
password: 'YOUR_PASSWORD_TO_ENCRYPT'
}
qpdf.encrypt(localFilePath, options, outputFilePath);
```

how can get localFilePath and outputFilePath on the firebase cloud function from the firebase storage pdf file or URL pdf file?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the pdf stored in firebase storage in your firebase function. you can download the pdf in temp storage run

```
qpdf.encrypt(localFilePath, options, outputFilePath);

localFilePath = /tmp/your-downloaded-file.pdf
outputFilePath = /tmp/your-output-file.pdf
```

once encrypted you can upload it to firebase cloud storage.

For more on local disk on firebase cloud function refer [local disk firebase cloud function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing#local_disk)

Comment: i am currently trying to make use of qpdf in a google cloud function context (not firebase) and it seems that qpdf is not available there. reference: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/system-packages . any workarounds?